# java item listener

Tags: java, swing

i need help regarding the save menu item i have in my menu bar. i have set the code to

```
private void smActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {


}
```

but i am unsure what needs to go inbetween the brackets? The gui is a form where poeple fill in there medical record e.g combo box "mr/mrs" textfield "medical problems" etc and when they click file save i would like the user to get a save box (like save as box in word) and the information to be saved in a txt file.

P.S. would it be possible to have the "file type" set to save as a txt file as default.

Comment: It's generally good practice to tag your homework as such.

Comment: its not homework. im trying to learn java from a book and this is one of the tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`JFileChooser#showSaveDialog()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showSaveDialog%28java.awt.Component%29) to ask the enduser to select a `File`.

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    // ...
} else {
    // User pressed cancel.
}
```

Comment: cheers mate, will give it a go. been struggling with this for a week thought it would be somthing like

Comment: slight problem mate, it shows the save box and the user can click save, but there is no file saved?

Comment: The `File` is just an abstract representation. You have to create the file and write some content to the file using basic [Java IO API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). Then it'll appear on the local disk file system. This is a completely different problem. Ask a new question if you stucks.

Comment: cheers mate, java IO is the next section in the book. will have a look and ask a new question if i have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe looking at this could help you. I don't fully understand what you need.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html